# Why didn't the Ghostbusters reply to the rector?

Tags: plot-explanation, ghostbusters

In *Ghostbusters* (1984), when they return to the University, the rector informs them that they are expelled, because the school doesn't want to finance their activities anymore.

Anyway, in the previous scene, they had a contact with a real ghost in a library, that makes their theories plausible, then they could save the situation by just telling it to the rector and showing the results.

Why didn't they tell that to the rector?

Comment: Given their low reputation with the university, and the fact that Venkman is actually a terrible scientist, why would the rector believe them? At best he'd think it was just a hoax.